# play framework runs evolution db script even when scala template gets changed

Tags: mysql, scala, ebean, playframework-2.3, playframework-evolutions

Consider A,B,C,D are models. A has one-to-many relationship with D. B has one-to-many relationship with D. B has one-to-many relationship with c.
In this design there are multiple many-to-one relationship in B. 
Whenever I have only one many-to-one relationship in B, it works fine. But when i add extra many-to-one relationship in B, play framework runs evolution db script even when scala template gets changed.

How to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you using for a database?